# Changing state but not rerendering react redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, state, store

I have been accessing store to change the state, I can even see the change in the console, but the ui isn't rerendering. [Here](https://github.com/shanemmay/test-3) is the repository of my code (it's extremely small and basic).
Why isn't my ui rerendering?

https://github.com/shanemmay/test-3

Comment: Can you post the relevant parts of your code here?

Comment: You have to connect components to the store so that store changes trigger a re-render. If they're not connected, they won't re-render when the store changes and thus won't reflect new store values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your **index.js**, you need to change the way you supply the store to your `App` component. It should be like this.

```
import {Provider} from 'react-redux'

ReactDOM.render( <Provider store={store}>
<App />
</Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Then in your **App.js**, you need to map the state to props and then display the number from that prop. And the most important thing, you must connect your react component to the redux store using `connect`. Below is how you need to modify your App.js

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';
 import {connect} from 'react-redux'


 class App extends Component {
   render() {
     return (
       <div>
         <h1>{this.props.number}</h1>
         <button onClick={
           () =>
           {
             this.props.dispatch({type:'+'});
           }
         }> + </button>
       </div>
     );
   }
 }

 const mapStateToProps = state => ({
   number: state
 })

 export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

Please do go through https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react to gain better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Your app need get connected with redux framwork using provider as madhu bhat said.

You have to follow the redux architecture, basic understanding will make to resolve this very simply.

**Basic Flow**

[image]

> Visit same kind of example in my respositary
>
> https://github.com/zural/react-redux-simple-counter/tree/master

This will make you to understand redux flow & react state.